# Consecutive permutation and combination in r

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to create a consecutive permutation of values in r, but not able to create it as per my need. this is expected

```
ID         Val  Perm 1  Perm 2  Perm3   Perm 4  Perm 5  Perm 6  Perm 7  Perm 8  Perm 9  Perm 10 Perm 11 Perm 12 Perm 13 Perm 14 Perm 15 Perm 16 Perm 17 Perm 18 Perm 19 Perm 20 Perm 21 Perm 22 Perm 23 Perm 24 Perm 25 Perm 26 Perm 27 Perm 28 Perm 29 Perm 30 Perm 31 Perm 32 Perm 33 Perm 34 Perm 35 Perm 36
 12,000      1  Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 12,581      2  Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 12,857      2  Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 13,387      5  Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 15,846      2  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 23,387      5  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 25,424      4  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1 Range 1 Range 1
 25,424      2  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 2 Range 1
 25,932      6  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 3 Range 2 Range 3 Range 2 Range 2
 25,932      1  Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3 Range 3
```

But instead I m getting other values like

```
apply(combinations(n=3,r=5,v = c("Range 1","Range 2","Range 3"),repeats.allowed = T),2,sort)
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
 [1,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1"
 [2,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2"
 [3,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2"
 [4,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2"
 [5,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2"
 [6,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2"
 [7,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3"
 [8,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3"
 [9,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3"
[10,] "Range 1" "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3"
[11,] "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3"
[12,] "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[13,] "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[14,] "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[15,] "Range 1" "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[16,] "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[17,] "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[18,] "Range 2" "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[19,] "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[20,] "Range 2" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
[21,] "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3" "Range 3"
```

the logic for preparing the permutations columns would be first column for permutation("Perm 1") be like keeping the "Range 1" constant and "Range 2" and "Range 3" changing , "Range 2" has been kept increasing and "Range 3" decreasing till column "Perm 8" and from column "Perm 9" the value "Range 1" has been incremented by 1 and "Range 2" and "Range 3" changing , "Range 2" has been kept increasing and "Range 3" decreasing till column "Perm 15" and from "Perm 16"th column the "Range 1" has again incremented by 2 and so on.

Can it be done using other function?
Thanks in advance.

Domnick.

Comment: Have you tried the `expand.grid` function? `v <-  c("Range 1","Range 2","Range 3");expand.grid(rep(list(v), 5))`

Comment: That gives me equal number of values("Range 1","Range 2", "Range 3") for each 5 columns

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern isn't typical. From what I could tell of your pattern, you can try this custom function

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(n) {
        require(purrr)
        require(dplyr)
        S <- "Range"
        df <- Reduce("data.frame", lapply(1:(n-2), function(x) data.frame(c(paste0(S, 1), rep(paste0(S, 2), x), rep(paste0(S, 3), n-x-1))))) %>%
                setNames(paste0("Perm", 1:(n-2)))
        return(df)
    }

df <- myfun(6)
   # Perm1  Perm2  Perm3  Perm4
# 1 Range1 Range1 Range1 Range1
# 2 Range2 Range2 Range2 Range2
# 3 Range3 Range2 Range2 Range2
# 4 Range3 Range3 Range2 Range2
# 5 Range3 Range3 Range3 Range2
# 6 Range3 Range3 Range3 Range3
```